# Dealing with ABSOLUTE VALUE and IF STATEMENT in linear integer programming

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to write a linear constraint that computes the absolute value of a difference, only if both the variables $x$ and $y$ are different from zero.

$x,y$ are binary variables while $s$ is a positive integer variable. $a$ and $b$ are positive integer coefficients.

$|xa-yb| \leq s$ only if $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$

for the first part I did:

$(xa-yb) \leq s$ and $-(xa-yb) \leq s$

but I don't know how to proceed with the second part, if that is ever possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change $\dots \le s$ to $\dots \le s + M(2 - x - y)$ where $M$ is an a priori upper bound on $|xa-yb|$. If either or both of the binary variables is 0, the inequality will not be restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce
$$(x = 1 \land y = 1) \implies |a-b| \le s$$
with linear constraint
$$|a-b|(x + y - 1) \le s.$$

Do you instead (or also) want to enforce
$$|a-b| \le s \implies (x = 1 \land y = 1),$$
which is the converse?